# Upgrading from 1.4.1 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-1.4

I am working on store upgradation from 1.4.1 to 1.9 for that i has tried following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662347/how-to-upgrade-magento-1-4-1-1-to-1-7-0-2 but after running the setup it is just loading in browser from last 10 hours.Please tell what is the problem. Why my site is just processing after upgrade. For the information my database tables are on myISAM engine i have converted required table to innoDB. Please guide me to update my store

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your existing database size upgrading can take a substantial amount of time - especially the conversion of the order `EAV` to `flat tables` (`1.4.2` I think).

However seeing that you are starting out from a potentially broken state (with `myISAM` you could have introduced integrity issues without even knowing it) I would suggest starting with a completely new install and then migrate your data (you might have to accept that some will be lost - but I think it is better to re-start with a correct database engine than perpetuating a previous mistake).

Answer (score 8):

For your level of upgrade I recommend starting with a fresh version of Magento 1.9 and running the database upgrade against that. The steps are as follows:

1) Clean all your log tables. This will increase the speed of your upgrade
2) Get current database dump of your website.
3) Setup a local environment and restore you CE1.4 database to a newly created database
4) Create you local.xml on your new CE 1.9 environment. 
5) If you can use MageRun (https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) it will greatly speed your process
6) Start the upgrade process by either opening your site in your browser, or a better option would be to use Magerun with the following command

```
n98-magerun.phar sys:setup:run
```

YOU DO NOT HAVE TO DO AN INCREMENTAL UPGRADE

Once the upgrade is complete you can then start with your theme and your modules. Both will not work correctly and will need proper Q/A

For more reference you can check Magento.com here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/manual_upgrade_using_fresh_install_and_original_database